# Android Things NXP iMX7D Unable to Connect to WiFi

Tags: android-wifi, android-things

Im trying to connect my Android Things NXP iMX7D board to wifi, but this is what i get https://pastebin.com/yhQhRCfr after

`am startservice -n com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService -a WifiSetupService.Connect -e ssid SleepMore -e passphrase mypass`

Any idea what is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: `SupplicantStaIfaceHal: Network is already saved, will not trigger remove and add operation`... Seems like it's already been configured. What do you get when executing `adb connect Android.local`?

Comment: Does your `passphrase` have any special characters (`space, !, ", $, &, ', (, ), ;, <, >, `, or |`)?

Comment: $ adb devices
 List of devices attached
 000000556d2a5022        device

 $ adb connect Android.local
 unable to connect to Android.local:5555: cannot resolve host 'Android.local' 
 and port 5555: Nieznany host. (11001)

My password is very simple with not special chars :)

Comment: Ok i was able to connect to other test wifi network. Maybe i have some issue with my router. Thanks for your response!